# How can I change change the message type to a web link url in wxpython balloontip

Tags: wxpython

How can I change change the message type to a web link url in wxpython balloontip ,which enable user clicking to open the link

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, that's not built-in to the widget. You could override the OnClose method and cause it to open a URL though. See http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.balloontip.BalloonFrame.html#lib-agw-balloontip-balloonframe which is called by BalloonTip (http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.balloontip.html)